# How to write a function with a generic AnyVal

Tags: scala

I'm trying to get the following Scala code to compile:

```
// Something that Scala is very bad at: don't try and figure out if every type I *could* possibly use supports it,
// just let me use it until I try a type that doesn't.  Or at least have AnyValue provide an abstraction for all
// Numeric Types (Interface)
trait NumericValue[T] {
  def +(rhs : T, lhs : T) : T
}
implicit object ByteNumericValue extends NumericValue[Byte] {
  def +(rhs : Byte, lhs : Byte) : Byte = (rhs + lhs).toByte
}
implicit object ShortNumericValue extends NumericValue[Short] {
  def +(rhs : Short, lhs : Short) : Short = (rhs + lhs).toShort
}
implicit object IntNumericValue extends NumericValue[Int] {
  def +(rhs : Int, lhs : Int) : Int = rhs + lhs
}
implicit object LongNumericValue extends NumericValue[Long] {
  def +(rhs : Long, lhs : Long) : Long = rhs + lhs
}
implicit object BigIntNumericValue extends NumericValue[BigInt] {
  def +(rhs : BigInt, lhs : BigInt) : BigInt = rhs + lhs
}

def doMath[T <: AnyVal](initializer : Long)(implicit Num : NumericValue[T]) : T = {
  Num.+(initializer.asInstanceOf[T], initializer.asInstanceOf[T])
}

lazy val math = doMath[Short](0)
```

The idea here is that I need a way to make doMath operate on any Integer and thus a type with an addition operator.  I want it to be agnostic of large number like BigInt or a very small number like Byte.

When I try to compile this I get an error:

```
error: could not find implicit value for parameter Num: NumericValue[Short]
lazy val math = doMath[Short](0)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Scala are you using?  It compiles fine for me (but gives a cast error since you can't cast a `Long` to a `Short`--if you change `initializer` to type `T` it all works fine).

Comment: you are doing exactly what scala Numeric is all about

Comment: Seems like you need to somehow implement widening of the numeric types when doing something else than combining two values of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Rex is right.  Since x : Long means x.asInstanceOf[Short] is invalid the routine fails when trying to cast initializer to T when T is short.  Yes, that seems legitimate.  Thanks Rex!  Wish you had answered instead of commented so I could give you a +1.

I do have some control over the type of initializer and given all that Byte is its logical type but I need to think about this a bit to make sure that's the only issue because the actual implementation of doMath uses a parameter to get a lazy value type with a bunch of options controlling the output.  But above is in its simplest form and I think you hit the nail on the head.  Thank you Rex Kerr!

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work in my circumstance.  I've given up for now but anyone's welcome to give Rex Kerr's suggestion a try as it may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit object is no good.

Try using case class instead

E.G:

```
case class LongNumericValue(l: Long) extends NumericValue[Long] {
  def +(l2 : Long) : Long = l + l2
}

def doMath[T <: AnyVal](implicit Num : NumericValue[T]) : T = {
  Num + Num
}
```

I'll explain:
In the above example doMath takes a single value of type NumericValue[T] (i.e. NumericValue[Long]) but if the received value is of type Long the compiler will look for implicit value for it, the case class.

Note I don't have my computer on me so I can't test this but it did with in the past when I tried to initialize a variable in that way.